# Pull Major Indices from Yahoo Finance

Tags: r, rvest, yahoo-finance

I would like to pull the Major World Indices Table from Yahoo Finance ([this](https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/)).

I have tried the following, but without success:

```
library(rvest)
yahoo_windizes <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/"
read_html(yahoo_windizes) %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    html_table()
```

Or with the `htmltab`-library:

```
library(htmltab)
yahoo_windizes %>%
    htmltab(which = 1)
```

I just can't seem to get it to work. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just in case you haven't heard of it already, you might want to consider the use of the `tidyquant` package. The last time that I used it, it had index returns (and more).

Comment: Thanks p0bs. I don't particularly want index returns, I first want a list of the major indices accross the globe. Does `tidyquant` provide such information?

Comment: Understood. In that case, you could try https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stock_market_indices for equity investment. That said, there are now more indices than stocks, given the rise of factor investing.

Comment: Thanks p0bs. I looked at that table and thought if possible I'd like to have the ticker symbols in the same pull. And thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 3 visible columns are canvas elements. Whilst it may be possible to get these values it may be easier to pull them from elsewhere and assign them to your data object.

In the meantime, if you want just the first 6 columns, you can re-construct the table in a number of ways, such as via a matrix:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

yahoo_windizes <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/"

table <- read_html(yahoo_windizes) %>%
  html_node("#list-res-table table") 

data <- map(1:6, function(x){ table %>% html_nodes(sprintf('td:nth-of-type(%i)', x)) %>% html_text()}) 

data <- data %>% unlist() %>% matrix(nrow=length(data[[1]]) , ncol=6) %>% as.tibble()

names(data) <- c('Symbol','Name','Last Price', 'Change', '%Change', 'Volume')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Would have been nice with the graphics, but I think I can make them on my own.